# Configure devise to use provider images for omniauth links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to do something like below in `/view/devise/shared/_links.html.erb` to set a different image for each provider link rendered in login/register views.

**Note:** Here I have not added links to images yet.

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>

    <% if provider == Facebook %>
      <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
    <% end %>
    <% if provider == Twitter %>
      <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
    <% end %>
    <% if provider == Google_Oauth2 %>
      <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
    <% end %>

  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

The original code was,

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

But I'm getting an error when opening the view.

> uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Facebook

It seems the provider names I've used are incorrect (but they are exactly what is rendered from `#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}`.

Is there a way I can look up what these need to be?

Or if theres a more optimal way to implement what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the respective gems' github pages and find out.

They must be `google_oauth2`, `facebook` and `twitter`

You can use

```
<% case provider %>
<% when :google_oauth2 %>
  ...
<% when :facebook %>
  ...
<% when :twitter %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: None of the links rendered when trying this.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you used `when` instead of `if` ?

Comment: It's just that the code looks pretty. It's upto you which one to use. You can accomplish the same stuff with `if elsif`. I just read that `if elsif` is faster than case. So may be you could use `if elsif`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<i> <% if provider == :Facebook %> </i>`, instead of `<% if provider == Facebook %>`   with symbol `":"`